# SQL - Finding how long the account haven't been paid

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below table:

```
+--------+------+---------+------------+
|   ID   | TEAM | WEEK_NO | Money_paid |
+--------+------+---------+------------+
| 112233 | AA   |  201801 |        100 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201801 |          0 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201802 |          0 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201803 |          0 |
| 454545 | AA   |  201801 |        100 |
| 658855 | BB   |  201802 |        100 |
| 658855 | BB   |  201802 |        100 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201809 |          0 |
+--------+------+---------+------------+
```

and I want the result like the below table with this rule that
Count the consecutive week_no.s where the Money_paid is same. It has be in consecutive order:

```
+--------+------+---------+------------+-------+
|   ID   | TEAM | WEEK_NO | Money_paid | Count |
+--------+------+---------+------------+-------+
| 112233 | AA   |  201801 |        100 |     1 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201801 |          0 |     3 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201802 |          0 |     3 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201803 |          0 |     3 |
| 454545 | AA   |  201801 |        100 |     1 |
| 658855 | BB   |  201802 |        100 |     1 |
| 112233 | BB   |  201809 |          0 |     1 |
+--------+------+---------+------------+-------+
```

So far I have tried many methods but none of them is any close to the desired result.

```
select top 10 
    Concat(TEAM, ID) AS Concatbu_ac, count(*) 
from 
    (select 
         *,
         (row_number() over (order by week_no) -
          row_number() over (partition by Concat(team, ID) order by week_no)
         ) as group5
     from 
         table5) t
group by 
    group5, Concat(team, ID);
```

Comment: You appear to think you have a gaps and islands problem.  Unfortunately, your sample data does not reveal this.  Please add sample data which shows what the actual problem is.

Comment: I have added an additional line to the above table to further assist in understnading the data set.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: You've completely stumped me +1.  I might recommend storing actual dates instead of the WEEK_NO, since that might make it easier to use `LAG` here.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the week based on amount paid by ID & Team. The idea is to count the record group by `ID, Team, Money_Paid`, then self join by unique column. Hope this answer your question.

```
DECLARE @dataset TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Team VARCHAR(10),
    Week_No INT,
    Money_Paid INT
)

INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 112233, 'AA', 201801, 100
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 112233, 'BB', 201801, 0
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 112233, 'BB', 201802, 0
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 112233, 'BB', 201803, 0
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 454545, 'AA', 201801, 100
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 658855, 'BB', 201802, 100 --duplicate
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 658855, 'BB', 201802, 100 --duplicate
INSERT INTO @dataset SELECT 112233, 'BB', 201809, 0

--week count
SELECT 
    ds.*,
    x.WeekCount
FROM @dataset ds
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        Team,
        COUNT(Week_No) AS WeekCount
    FROM @dataset
    GROUP BY ID, Team, Money_Paid
) x
ON ds.ID = x.ID
AND ds.Team = x.Team
ORDER BY ID, Team, Week_No

--week to date
SELECT 
    ds.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Team, Money_Paid ORDER BY ID, Team, Week_No) AS WeekToDate
FROM @dataset ds
```